# Grease Lines appearing to "shimmer"

Tags: grease-pencil

I just started using the grease pencil feature the other day and have run into an issue.

When I run the animation my lines/color layers seem to "shimmer" even though they aren't moving. It looks considerably worse when the camera is animated.

[This scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjMwZCFDYlM) has no animation, yet you'll see that there is movement in the lines and colors, seeming to sort of glitch out. I know there's something I must have missed in setting this up.

[Better example of the "shimmering" effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O0ve5rQjk4).

Comment: Hello, are you using a noise modifier on the lines ? It resets every frame if you don't force a seed in the modifier options. Although the effect is very subtle in your example video so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Hi! It's pretty random with how bad it looks, that render didn't turn out as bad as it sometimes does. I didn't use a noise modifier, but i did use the 'Draw Noise' setting for the draw tool, could that be the cause of this? Thanks so much for responding!

Comment: I don't think so, the noise is baked into the stroke when you use draw noise, there is no reason it should change with frames. It might be Z-fighting ? Try moving the culprit lines or fills a tiny bit further away or closer to the camera and see if it improves

Answer (score 0):

It may be some camera setting, so try a new camera.  I just had unwanted shimmering in  an eevee animation and replacing the camera helped identify the issue (clip length was too small).